# How do you sentence diagram a gerund when it does not act as the verb or the subject?

Tags: prepositions, gerunds, diagramming

I am looking to diagram this quote from *The Lord of the Rings:The Return of the King*:
**"They kept going because they were holding on to something. That there's some good in this world, Mr. Frodo, and it's worth fighting for."**

I am struggling to figure out how to diagram the last clause "it's worth fighting for."
"it" is the subject, "is" acts as the verb, and "worth" acts as the predicate adjective.
However, I am struggling how to fit "fighting for" into the diagram. "fighting" is a gerund, and "for" is a preposition. How would you diagram that part? As well as the rest of the quote because I am not quite sure I am diagramming that correctly either.

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 5):

> *it's* [*worth fighting for*]

"Worth" is an adjective here, with the subordinate "fighting" clause functioning as its complement.

The missing complement of "for" is "it", which is anaphoric to "some good in this world".

Answer (score -1):

English is not my mother tongue, however, the answer lies in the following passage taken from Collins Cobuild online dictionary;

4. ADJECTIVE B1
   If you say that something is worth having, you mean that it is pleasant or useful, and therefore a good thing to have.
   He's decided to get a look at the house and see if it might be worth buying.
   If this was what his job required, then the job wasn't really worth having.
   Most things worth having never come easy.
5. ADJECTIVE B1
   If something is worth a particular action, or if an action is worth doing, it is considered to be important enough for that action.
   No one is worth a great deal of sacrifice.
   I am spending a lot of money and time on this boat, but it is worth it.
   This restaurant is well worth a visit.
   It is worth pausing to consider these statements from Mr Davies.

So, it should be adjective. Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Ismail,

Comment: You could be a bit clearer: *worth* is an adjective but the -ing form *fighting* is not.